# Need help implementing GCDWebServer with GCDWebServerDataRequest

Tags: gcdwebserver

In the past I've used GCDWebServer to handle GET request passing query parameters. I now need to set it up to handle POST requests passing JSON objects. I could not find direct examples or descriptions of how this may be done with GCDWebServer, but I found request type GCDWebServerDataRequest that appears to be what I would need. Problem is none of available GCDWebServer's methods allow me to declare a handler that would take that type. I did not get far by tweaking GCDWebServer declarations either. Nor did I find any relevant posts. Does anyone have experience making this work successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere very early in the process of trying out various approaches to solve my problem I must've overlooked the obvious one: to simply pass request class parameter as GCDWebServerDataRequest.self in the call to "addHandlerForMethod". This basically does it! Here is sample code:

```
let webServer = GCDWebServer()
webServer.addHandlerForMethod("POST",
path: myPath,
requestClass: GCDWebServerDataRequest.self) { (request: GCDWebServerRequest!, completionBlock: GCDWebServerCompletionBlock!) in
    self.myHandler(request, completionBlock: completionBlock)}
```

myHandler method now receives request object as GCDWebServerDataRequest